# Implementing Data Frames in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, menhir

I have been learning OCaml on my own and I've been really impressed with the language. I wanted to develop a small machine learning library for practice but I've been presented with a problem.

In Python one can use Pandas to load data files then pass it to a library like Scikit-Learn very easily. I would like to emulate the same process in OCaml. However, there doesn't seem to be any data frames library in OCaml. I've checked 'ocaml-csv' but it doesn't really seem to be doing what I want. I also looked into 'Frames' from Haskell but it uses TemplateHaskell but I believe a simpler way to do the same thing should be possible if Pandas can simply load the data file into memory without compile-time metaprogramming.
Does anyone know how data frames are implemented in Pandas or R, a quick search on Google doesn't seem to return useful links.

Is it possible to use a parser generator such as Menhir to parse CSV files? Also, I'm unsure how static typing works with data frames.

Answer (score 1):

Would you have a reference about the format of *data frames*?  It may not be so hard to add to [`ocaml-csv`](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-csv) if CSV is the underlying representation.  The better is to [open an issue](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-csv/issues) with a request and the needed information.

Comment: I think that the main issue to address for implementing data frames is how to represent the parsed data in a statically typed language. Most CSV files have types such as integers/floats/strings. Currently 'ocaml-csv' uses 'string list list' as the underlying container.

To generate the data frame we need to have a tabular form where each column is of the same type.We would have something like
'type possible = int option * float option * string option'
'type g = possible list list'
where we encode all possible conversions for each input seen. Then we need to convert them to the concrete type.

Comment: If the relationship between the OCaml types and the CSV layout is sufficiently rigid, that could be implemented as preprocessor generated functions (à la sexp: declare your types, have the conversion with CSV be automated).